# influence or influences?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-agreement

> "Parents play a crucial role in determining what does, or doesn't, influence their teens."

In the above sentence, should the word "influence" be replaced by "influences"? Please explain.

Comment: I think it should be: Parents play a crucial role in determining what influences or what doesn't influence their teens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  With a bit of reordering for grammatical clarity, it becomes obvious that the verb phrase in its entirety is "does or does not influence".  In this case, because the verb phrase is **"does influence"** the issue of subject-verb agreement is handled by the "does".

For example:

- It does influence their teens.
- They do influence their teens.

Comment: @user44702 you might consider reading through the entire [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).